# Java Application can be published with Websphere but can't be exposed through IHS

Tags: windows, websphere, was7, ihs

I am trying to set up a Websphere/IHS configuration for testing a project in my development machine.

I have Websphere 7 (developer version) and IHS 7 installed on a Windows 7 machine. I can reach my application on Websphere 7 entering the URL *http://[my-host]:9080/myapp* and that's how I have been testing it so far. Now I need to expose my application through the IHS so I can reach it by entering the URL *http://[my-host]/myapp*.

I have gone through the proccess of 1)Stopping Web Server, 2)Generate Plug-in, 3)Distribute Plugin, 4)Start Web Server with different variables with no luck.

I know the plugin file (*plugin-cfg.xml*) is in *C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\HTTPServer\Plugins\config\[server-name]*. The file actually includes *myapp* as Uri in the UriGroup.

I'm actually a Websphere and IHS newbie, so if you think I need to give more information or send actual files, please tell me and gladly help you help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `httpd.conf` includes a reference to the plugin, and it points to the specific plugin configuration file you're checking, correct? (And actually, I don't know if quotes are required around the path.)

   `WebSpherePluginConfig C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\HTTPServer\Plugins\config\[server-name]\plugin-cfg.xml`
2. The Name attribute in the `UriGroup` that contains your webapp context-root specifies which virtual host is handling that context-root. Technically, it refers to a `Route` element which refers to a `VirtualHostGroup`. Does that `VirtualHostGroup` contain the hostname:port combination on which you're trying to access your application?
3. If all of that is correct, what's the specific error that is occurring? Timeout? 404? 500? Check the IHS log files and the plugin log file, which you can locate via the `Log` element in `plugin-cfg.xml`.
4. You can also change the `LogLevel` attribute in the `Log` element. It can take the values `Error`, `Warn`, `Stats`, or `Trace`, with `Error` being the least amount of logging and `Trace` the greatest.

Comment: The first point was missing... I still had to add a module reference so I could load the configuration (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268651). It is also important to install the IBM Installation Manager to get the module dll.